# How to troubleshoot Avi Vantage Service Engine connection to Controller in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I'm trying to get Avi running in EC2, using these instructions:

https://kb.avinetworks.com/installing-avi-vantage-in-amazon-web-services/

I've got the Controller running and a Virtual Service configured. The Controller even starts up an EC2 instance for the Service Engine. Unfortunately, the Service Engine never seems to connect to the Controller (see screenshots below).

For testing purposes, I've configured the controller's Security Group to allow all incoming TCP connections.

What's the best way to troubleshoot this to find out why the Service Engine can't connect?

[image: Service engine instance]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The SE uses secure channel to communicate with the controller. There are 3 requirements for secure channel negotiation:
1. The SE has been configured with the correct SSL certificates
2. The SE has a valid auth-token
3. The SE can communicate with the controller on port 8443 and 22

Steps 1 and 2 ensure that only an SE image that was created by the controller can connect to it. These steps should be taken care of automatically by the controller during creation/deployment of the SE.

In versions 16.1 and greater, we have an api that will display details of the secure channel connections. To view secure channel details for SE's, use the following API call:

https:///api/securechannel-status?is_controller=false

If you are unable to root cause the secure channel failure from the above information, or if you are running a version prior to 16.1, you can further troubleshoot SE to Controller communication by logging  into the SE via SSH or console. Since the SE has not yet connected to the controller, the SE's username/password will be the default admin/admin. Then confirm that both of the following are true:

1. The SE is able to telnet to the controller on port 8443.
2. The SE is able to SSH to the controller on port 22.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll try that out.